# Is there a way for numbers to exceed the integer max in lua using string values?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm talking about rbx.Lua so if you don't know it well, don't try to answer this

```
function ConvertShort(num, cool)
    local x = tostring(num)
    if #x >= 16 then
        local important = (#x - 15)
        cool.Value = x:sub(0,(important)).."."..(x:sub(#x-13,(#x-13))).."qd"
    elseif #x >= 13 then
        local important = (#x-12)
        cool.Value = x:sub(0,(important)).."."..(x:sub(#x-10,(#x-10))).."T"
    elseif #x>= 10 then
        local important = (#x - 9)
         cool.Value = x:sub(0,(important)).."."..(x:sub(#x-7,(#x-7))).."B"
    elseif #x >= 7 then
        local important = (#x-6)
        cool.Value = x:sub(0,(important)).."."..(x:sub(#x-5,(#x-5))).."M"
    elseif #x >= 4 then
        cool.Value =  x:sub(0,(#x-3)).."."..(x:sub(#x-2,(#x-2))).."k"
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)
    local cash = Instance.new("StringValue", plr)
    cash.Name = "cash"
    cash.Value = "0"
    cash.Changed:connect(function()
            ConvertShort(tonumber(cash.Value), cash)
    end)
end)
```

So, when it gets to quadrillions it shows a nubmer like 1e+1.1k, which is not what I'm needing it to be like, I need it to be more like "1qd", and I have no idea how to fix this or if there even is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
local x = tostring(num)
```

with this code:

```
local x = ""
while num >= 1000000 do
  x, num = x.."0", math.floor(num / 10)
end
x = tostring(num)..x
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
local x = tostring(num)
```

with

```
local x = string.format("%.0f", num)
```